# gbm.step Error in `[.data.frame`(y.data, model.mask) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, gbm

I am trying to do a boosted regression tree in R using gbm.step.

I try to run the following code:

```
CrabeatBRT <- gbm.step(data=crab2,
                       gbm.x=1:5,
                       gmb.y=6:7,
                       offset=NULL, 
                       fold.vector=NULL,
                       family="bernoulli",
                       tree.complexity=1,
                       learning.rate=0.01,
                       bag.fraction=0.5)
```

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please show us some data you are using.

Comment: Since the documentation for `gbm.step` states "gbm.y: index or name of response variable in data": are you sure it is possible to use `gbm.y = 6:7`? I would have expected `gbm.y = 6` or `gbm.y=7`. In addition, there is a typo: `gmb.y` instead of `gbm.y`.

Comment: @MartinGal is correct, you cannot do a bernoulli with 2 response variable